# measure customized dojo widget performance

Tags: performance, testing, dojo, widget, customization

In our application we have customized dojo widgets and we would like to calculate the performance in term of widget loading time and the time to load the large data sets with in widgets.

Could any one please let me know, do we have any tools available in the market to measure the performance of the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I would use dojo unit tests frameworks DOH. Specifically [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/util/doh.html#performance-tests) section. You might also find testing tools like [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) [useful](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/) although I don't recommend it for [this](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/faq.html#would_you_recommend_using_selenium_grid_for_performanceload_testing) reason.